# iOS programming: understand in more detail about first responder

Tags: ios, uitextfield, first-responder

I have an iOS project with a text field and a button. Clicking the text field making it first responder and the keyboard is called. And when I click the button after that, the keyboard is still on the screen and the text field is still first reponsder. Natural thinking, clicking the button should make the it the first responder and force the text filed to resign, but why does this process not happen in Xcode? 
    If my application has 2 buttons A and B, will clicking A making it first responder? And will clicking B after that making B first responder and A will resign?

Answer (score 0):

The first responder is whatever control is currently ready to respond to actions.

In UIKit this is usually the control that has activated the keyboard and is receiving input. If you want that text control to stop waiting for input – which in turn dismisses the keyboard – you should call its resignFirstResponder() method, which passes the first responder baton to the next waiting component.

In your case, if you want to close the keyboard you can do 2 things:

1. You can call resignFirstResponder() of the text field
2. In your IBAction of a button, you can write `self.view.endEditing(true)`, which will close the keyboard for you.

Please comment if you have any questions.

Happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

If you're coming from other environments - such as a web page on a desktop browser - you can "tab" from element to element, giving each element the "focus."

In iOS, UI elements do not have such a "focus" state.

If you tap in a `UITextField` or `UITextView`, for example, that object becomes the `firstResponder` and because it accepts keyboard input, the keyboard is shown. A `UIButton` does *not*, by default, have `canBecomeFirstResponder` enabled, and does not accept keyboard input.

That's why tapping a button does not dismiss the keyboard - or "take the focus away" from the text field.

You *can* subclass `UIButton` to give it those properties, or, as shown in another answer, add code to tell the text field to `resignFirstResponder`, but that is not the default behavior.